# Replace a filepath column in SQL with new file structure

Tags: sql-server, sql

I have recently changed the structure of a drive where I keep a lot of my 'estimating' files.

The problem is, I use a program that has references to some of those files, in the old structure, stored in a SQL database.

I would like to be able to use a SQL query to Replace the start of the string in the "ImagePath" column with the new file path. Or if someone can suggest a better way of doing this!?

The old structure was:

`X:\Estimating Dept\Estimating Files\Estimates\E28000 - E28999\E28600 - E28699\E28654\...`

I need the new filepath to be:

`S:\E28xxx\6xx\54\...`

I have tried the following SQL command:

`UPDATE
    BidPages
SET
    ImagePath = REPLACE(ImagePath,"X:\Estimating Dept\Estimating Files\Estimates\E28000 - E28999\E28600 - E26899\E28654","S:\Estimates\E28xxx\6xx\54\")`

in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008, but I get the error:

`Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'X:\Estimating Dept\Estimating Files\Estimates\E28000 - E28999\E28600 - E28699\E28654'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'S:\Estimates\E28xxx\6xx\54\'.`

The table name I want to update is `dbo.BidPages` and the column name is `ImagePath`.

Also, is there a way to increment the digits in the filepath based on the original filepath?

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I need to use single quotes, as opposed to double quotes.